# Using xslt 1.0 I want to add days to current date when <date> is less than current date. I'm using java SimpleDateFormat for comparison

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

Is this valid using java syntax for xslt? I do not have an xml transformation tool that supports java for my validation so I'm not sure if the syntax is correct. If not could anyone please let me know if there is any other approach that I can take?

So if the `RequestedDeliveryDate` is less than current date then add 5 days to current date and that will be the new `RequestedDeliveryDate`.

XSLT im using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" /> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/ShippingInfo/RequestedDeliveryBy">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'), java:java.util.Date.new()) &gt;= '.')">
                <RequestedDeliveryBy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'), java:java.util.Date.new(),5)" />
                </RequestedDeliveryBy>
            </xsl:when>             
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />        
            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>                        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tXML>
    <Message>
        <Order> 
            <OrderLines> 
                <OrderLine>
                    <ShippingInfo> 
                        <RequestedDeliveryBy>12/04/2015 23:59</RequestedDeliveryBy>
                    </ShippingInfo>                  
                </OrderLine> 
            </OrderLines>
        </Order> 
    </Message>
</tXML>
```

Comment: ok added it in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use XSLT 1.0 with Java and Xalan.  Seeing date manipulation in XSLT makes me anxious.  Date handling isn't really XSLT's strong suit.  As you are already resigned to using a Java method let's make Java do the hard work.

I'm assuming you are programmatically invoking your transform (e.g. so Xalan can access the Java method that the XSLT references):

```
TransformerFactory tFactory
    = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("Transform.xsl"));
transformer.transform(new StreamSource("Test.xml"),
    new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("Out.xml")));
```

We can write a nice simple class to process your RequestDeliveryBy date.

I'm using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) here because it is easier than the old date-time classes bundled with early versions of Java. If you are using Java 8 or later you can instead use the new built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

```
package com.example;

import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ProcessDate {

    private static final String DATEPATTERN = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FMT = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATEPATTERN);

    public static String process(final String date) {  
        String result = date;
        LocalDateTime now = new LocalDateTime();
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, FMT);
        if (now.isAfter(dt)) {
            result = FMT.print(now.plusDays(5));
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

So with Java doing all the heavy lifting your **Transform.xsl** becomes nice and simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="java">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" /> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/ShippingInfo/RequestedDeliveryBy">
        <RequestedDeliveryBy><xsl:value-of select="java:com.example.ProcessDate.process(string(.))"/></RequestedDeliveryBy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This Answer is good except that it ignores s crucial issue: time zone. If you fail to specify a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is assumed to apply when parsing that string. If you meant to ignore time zone entirely ( rarely a good idea ), use [`LocalDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html).

Comment: This surely is a great solution with the java class. But I'm not at liberty to add it to the java utils. Would it be possible to do it without adding a class. I'm not totally inclined toward using java. I can definitely use another approach without java.

Comment: Possible, I dare say.  Easy, probably not.  Worthwhile, jury's out.  Posside options; 1. use Xalan with embedded JavaScript - date processing can be tricky in JavaScript without using a library.  2. use an XSLT processor that supports the "unstable" date functions of EXSLT http://exslt.org/date/index.html (still a tricky option!). 3. Don't use XSLT but use something else to process your XML, something with good XML and date support (e.g. Python, Ruby, Java, Perl, C# etc.).

Comment: 3.5. You could also pre-process the XML with something other than XSLT before transforming it with XSLT (a pipeline!).